# Run typescript-eslint-parser

Tags: typescript, eslint

With eslint you can run it as script with:

```
scripts: {
  lint: "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --ext .js",
}
```

I've changed to typescript and are using typescript-eslint-parser. Works in webstorm. But how do I run it as script?
Changing extension to .ts is not working

```
  lint: "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --ext .ts",
```

The error:
`error  Missing file extension "ts" for "../controller/..`

Comment: Regarding the documentation, in your ESLint configuration file, you should use `"parser": "typescript-eslint-parser"`. Is that what you mean when you say that you change to typescript-eslint-parser?

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `tslint` instead then?

Comment: @NicolasCami. Changed from javscript to typescript and using "parser": "typescript-eslint-parser"

Comment: @H.B. No. Eslint is more mature.

Comment: Did you add `"plugins": ["typescript"]` in your ESLint configuration file?

Comment: @NicolasCami. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are missing a required parameter. If you run with your existing config it will give below output

```
$ npm run lint

> node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --ext .ts

eslint [options] file.js [file.js] [dir]
```

The `file` or `directory` is required. So either change it to

```
scripts: {
  lint: "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --ext .ts index.ts",
}
```

Which is for a specific file, or if you want all `ts` files then use

```
scripts: {
  lint: "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --ext .ts .",
}
```

Comment: I get "error  Missing file extension "ts" for "../controller..."

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the complete exception in there? @Per

Comment: Yes. I've added.

Comment: You probably will have to provide a minimal git repo to debug this. It may be that there some file that is causing the issue. The error message though is not helpful for someone else to debug it for you